# Check if a value of dataframe doesnt exists in the dictionary using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
          movieName  Year
            Iron Man  2008
  X-Men Dark Phoenix  2014
      Doctor Strange  2007
          Spider-Man  2014
   x-Men First class  2006
     Captain America  2011
```

And i have this dictionary

```
dict = {'Spider-Man':'The amazing Spider-Man', 'X-Men Dark Phoenix': 'X-Men Days of future',
'x-Men First class':'x-Men:The last stand' }
```

how can i check that the value of dataframe doesnt exists in the dictionary and print the row for exp Iron man and Captain America they dont exist int the dict how can i check this using pandas.

**Expected output:**

```
 movieName  Year
    Iron Man  2008
    Captain America  2011
```

Comment: `df[~df["movieName"].isin(your_dict.keys())]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First dont use `dict` for variable, because builten (python code word). You can use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with keys of dict:

```
d = {'Spider-Man':'The amazing Spider-Man', 
     'X-Men Dark Phoenix': 'X-Men Days of future',
     'x-Men First class':'x-Men:The last stand' }

df1 = df[~df['movieName'].isin(d.keys())]
print (df1)
         movieName  Year
0         Iron Man  2008
2   Doctor Strange  2007
5  Captain America  2011
```